# How to run batch file with parameters in java?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, parameters

I have created a jar file called test.jar under C:\jars. I have JAR file under the same location named run.bat and it contains the below code -

```
@echo off

set exec_path=C:\jars java -cp %exec_path%/test.jar; com.mycomp.myapp.MyProgram "%1"%*

@echo on
```

It is running successfully from command prompt with parameters.

Now I would like to run it from another JAVA program.
Please suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: `cmd /c test.bat`. batch files are not executable, so you execute a `cmd` shell and tell it to run the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this issue before. The answer is that you have to run cmd.exe or bash or whatever shell you've got, then feed in the command to that process via the process input/output streams.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd");
p.getOutputStream().write("mybatch.bat\n");
```

Comment: How can I pass parameters?

Comment: You can simply do `p.getOutputStream().write("mybatch.bat 1 2 3\n");`. Here I have passed 3 parameters.

Comment: p.getOutputStream().write() is not accepting a String as parameter. I tried by converting them to bytes but it is not working.